# Java EE - JSF - Entity class @ManyToOne

Tags: java, jsf, oracle11g, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

First of all sorry for my dump english but i would ask a little help..

I have two oracle Db tables (events,documents) and i made two entity classes.

```
one:
public class BDocuments implements Serializable {
 @JoinColumn(name = "B_EVENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private BEvents bEventId;
...
...
two:
public class BEvents implements Serializable {
 @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="EventSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="EventSeq",sequenceName="B_EVENTS_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
...

...
```

the id field of event table is the foreign key for the documents table event_id field..
Whene the user create a new event on the view the program create a new instance to the events table and if the events has an attached document then i’ll create a instance to the documents table. And of course the new event instance’s id will be the new document instance’s event_id..

it workd fine.. there is no probleme if i check the tables with TOAD i can see the 2 new instance..

After this i’ll see the new event ont he view and if I’ll click on this int he new dialog window i should see the events details.. like does this event has any attached documents..

JSF:

```
<p:column>
 <f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Esemény ID"/>
</f:facet>
<h:commandLink value="#{item.id}" >
<p:ajax  listener="#{mainWorkingBean.showChosedEventDetails('dlgshowevent',item.id)}"  />
</h:commandLink>
</p:column>
<p:column>
```

There is a managed beans that has a metod showChosedEventDetails() and after some validation check it invoke the DAO EJB’s following method, and then create a data table for the view by the returned List.
This is EJB method:

```
 public List<BDocuments> showAllDocumentsOnEvents(Integer chosedEventid) {
    if (chosedEventid != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("showAllDocumentsOnEvents: event id:" + chosedEventid);
            assert emf != null;
            EntityManager em = null;
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            List<BDocuments> documentList = new ArrayList();
            BEvents documentDetailsInstance = (BEvents)  em.createNamedQuery("BEvents.findById").setParameter("id", chosedEventid).getSingleResult();
            //get the event instance by the id that received in the method paramter…  
            System.out.println("showAllDocumentsOnEvents NEW CHOSED INSTANCE:  " + documentDetailsInstance);
            Collection<BDocuments> allDocumentsCollection = documentDetailsInstance.getBDocumentsCollection(); //a @ManytoOne..
            System.out.println("showAllDocumentsOnEvents EVENTINSTANCE: " + documentDetailsInstance.getEventText());
            System.out.println("showAllDocumentsOnEvents COLLECTION: " + allDocumentsCollection.toString());
            System.out.println("showAllDocumentsOnEvents NEW COLLECTION SIZE..: " + allDocumentsCollection.size() + "collection: " + allDocumentsCollection.toString()); // lame debugging.. checking the values..  
            int x;
            for (x = 0; x < allDocumentsCollection.size();) {
                System.out.println("Show all: for ciklus: Iterables kiszedve:  " + Iterables.get(allDocumentsCollection, x));
                BDocuments document = Iterables.get(allDocumentsCollection, x);
                documentList.add(document);
                x++;
            } //check the collection and put the elements to the list.. .
            return documentList;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(" showAllDocumentsOnEvents ELSE ÁG...showAllDocumentsOnEvents: event id:" + chosedEventid);
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is ALSO work fine BUT the Collection allDocumentsCollection is empty! 
I couldn’t be empty because i can see in the database there is in everything what should be in.

And now comming the real big question.. after i make clean and build and redeploy in netbeans and then click ont he same event on the view the Collection allDocumentsCollection WILL NOT BE empty… 
I’m really don’t know why is this Collection empty before the redeploy.. and why not after the redeploy..

I would be really thankfull if somebody could help me..

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd that you showed everything but the getBDocumentsCollection mapping that is causing you problems, or the code used to set the relationships.  But since you are saying the database is populated correctly and this is a bidirectional relationship, it is a fairly common mistake to only populate one side of the relationship.  When you set the BDocuments.bEventId with a BEvents instance, you must also add that BDocuments instance to the BEvents.BDocumentsCollection to keep the relationship in synch with the database.  JPA does not maintain relationships for you, so you either set both sides, or constantly refresh the object from the database when the transaction commits using em.refresh or provider specific api.  Since refreshing has additional overhead, it is much better to just always keep both sides in sync.

Comment: but sorry, how could i give a BDocuments instance to the BEvents.BDocumentsCollection? the setter method wait for a BDocumentsCollection

Comment: success! :) before persisting this object: BDocuments newDocument = new BDocuments(); i had to add : savedEvent.getBDocumentsCollection().add(newDocument); and it works! :)